# need to download the link from mail using app script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I am having an issue with app script, I am trying to download the link pasted in the content to drive.

mail sample is like below

Report download URL: xxxxxx.xlsx

the above xxxxx.xlsx is a link from which we download the file.
I tried below app script code.other attachements got downloaded to drive, but above link is not getting downloaded. please help.

```
function saveAttachmentInFolder(){
  const folderId = 'Drive id';
  const searchQuery = 'Report download URL';
  const threads = GmailApp.search(searchQuery, 0,25);
  threads.forEach(thread => {
    const messages = thread.getMessages();
        messages.forEach(message => {
        const attachments = message.getAttachments({
          includeInlineImages: false,
          includeAttachments: true
      });
        attachments.forEach(attachment => {
        Drive.Files.insert(
          {
            title: attachment.getName(),
            mimeType: attachment.getContentType(),
            parents: [{ id: folderId }]
          },
          attachment.copyBlob()
        );
      });
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Is the file attached to the email itself, or does the email simply contain a link to download the file?

Comment: email contains the link to download the file,file is not attached

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious that you cannot get it with `getAttachments` because it is not an attachment

You may need to scrape the content of the email.

```js
/*
declare before the loop
const urls = [];
*/

const body = message.getBody();
//const body = message.PlainBody();
// you may need to adjust it in case there is any html code
const match = body.match(/Report download URL:.*(\S+\.xlsx)/);
if (match) { urls.push(match[1]); }
```

References:

[getBody()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getbody)

[getPlainBody()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getplainbody)

Comment: But how do you download links from there?